# How can we run the flutter app in iOS simulator from Macbook Air M1?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am new to flutter, i have installed Android studio and Xcode 14.0.1 already.
I am able to run the app on actual iOS device from Xcode which is working fine,
also same it's working from Android studio for Android Device.

But when i am trying to run the iOS Runner in the simulator it's throwing some error as

Here is the screenshot of that error.

[image]

**Details**

```
Application launch for 'com.lifting.recording did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-11-04 09:16:50 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.0 (20A360)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 1472;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--
```

**System Information**

```
macOS Version 12.6 (Build 21G115)
Xcode 14.0.1 (21336) (Build 14A400)
Timestamp: 2022-11-04T14:46:50+05:30
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.